# react-hook-form's validate function always returns errors

Tags: reactjs, use-form

This is the one that occurs problem.

```js
 <input
     type="text"
     name="nickname"
     {...register('nickname', {
     required: true,
     validate: async (value) =>
        value !== profile?.nickname &&
        (await validateNickname(value).catch(() => {
         return 'Invalid nickname.';
        })),
     })}
     placeholder="Nickname"
     />
```

- If the input value is not same with the defaultValue
- and It's duplicated with another nickname, (`validateNickname` function returns error)
  Then, error message is registered 'Invalid nickname.'
  and the errors object looks like this below.

```js
{
 nickname:
 message: "Invalid nickname."
 ref:...
 type: "validate"
}
```

but the problem is

- If I input the value which is same with the defaultValue,
- or If I input not duplicated value,
  The errors object should be empty.
  but it still returns error like this below.

```js
{
 nickname:
 message: ""
 ref:...
 type: "validate"
}
```

so there's no error message registered, but somehow, error is exist.

Please let me know if there's anything I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: why you are using ( ? ) and ( . ) in validation. Like:  profile?.nickname

Answer (score 0):

This could be the problem:

```
(await validateNickname(value).catch(() => {
         return 'Invalid nickname.';
        }))
```

You want to return a boolean in your AND expression, but you are returning a string, which would be saying the validation is correct.
If you want to handle that validation error so as to display the message in html you can do a simple error handling approach like this one (using named validations):

```
// ... your validation set up
validate:{
    validateNickname_ : async (value) => {
        let response = false;
        await validateNickname(value)
            .then( () => { response = true;})
            .catch(() => { response = false;});
        return value !== profile?.nickname && response;
    }
}

// ... showing your error message
{
    errors.nickname && errors.nickname.type=="validateNickname_" &&
    <p className='error-form-msg'>
    {"Your custom error message here ..."}
    </p>
}
```